# Does the Sequelize constructor have a default database value if non supplied?

Tags: sequelize.js

I used Sequelize to connect to a local PostSQL database in a Node.js app using the following values. Notice the typo. This did not prevent Sequelize connecting. In fact, it worked and  connected to a database called 'nicholaslee' (myname).

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  **datebase**: 'mvc',
  username: 'postgres',
  password: null,
  dialect: 'postgres'
})
```

Why did Sequelize continue to connect ? Where did it find a database named after myself?